# Services and TPL

Tags: c#

I'm creating a Windows service and so have the `Program` class inheriting from the `ServiceBase` class and overriding `OnStart` and `OnStop`. Inside these methods I have made use of TPL instead of using `Thread`s like I would have done in the past. This what the methods look like:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);

    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!DoWork())
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }, cancellationToken);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    base.OnStop();
}
```

I was wondering if someone could just review the code to make sure it all looked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while (true)
> {
>     if (!DoWork())
>     {
>         _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         await Task.Delay(1000);
>     }
>
>     if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
>     {
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Actually this could be a one-liner:

```
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && DoWork()) await Task.Delay(1000);
```

but why isn't `DoWork` awaitable and taking a cancellation token?

```
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) await DoWork(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Didn't even think of refactoring it that way! And `DoWork` hasn't actually been written yet I'm getting the framework in place. I might see about making it `async`.

Comment: On your second point I've changed it to: `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await _stationWork.DoWorkAsync())  {  await Task.Delay(1000); }`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I like it ;-)